# Passing asynch initial state to useReducer and is return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm fetching asych data in parent component and in VersionContainer i want use it like a initialState and pass to context provider. But when I do that in this way my values in ContentVersionProvider are undefined. What is the problem?

```
const VersionContainer: React.FC<IProps> = ({ data }) => {
    const initialState: Partial<IVersionHistoryContext> = data;
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(versionReducer, initialState);
    return (
        <ContentVersionsProvider value={dispatch}>
            <ContentVersionProvider value={state}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-6 p-0">
                        <VersionPreview />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-6 p-0">
                        <Version />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentVersionProvider>
        </ContentVersionsProvider>
    );
};

export default VersionContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing `initialState` to `useReducer` won't update the state when the `data` is updated.

Meaning, if `data` is `undefined` and it becomes available, it won't update `state`.

Therefore you need to pass the `data` only when its available:

```
data && <VersionContainer data={data}/>
```

Comment: Even when I use your solutions in parent component is not work still undefined

Comment: Do you have reproducible example? Did you log your data to see if its undefined? How you reading the values?